# How to query the AccountSource in SOQL?

Tags: soql, account

`Select AccountSource from Account` is an invalid SOQL query, but the `AccountSource` clearly lives on the `Account` object.  It's a standard field.

How can I access it via SOQL?

Comment: `SELECT AccountSource FROM account` is a valid soql. And it's working. Check your soql for spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can directly add that field in soql query, its working fine for me.
**select Id,AccountSource from account** , check with field level security and field accessibility.

Comment: Very strange.  It does appear to work now.  Despite my apparent incompetence, I would like to understand what's going on.  Between running queries I thought should work, I've tried various tools that purport to unload sfdc data (cloudally, jitterbug).  I wonder if one may have changed field visibility without my knowledge.  Does this sound possible?

Comment: Yes, it might be changed by your admin or other else. If it does appear, then you can add it in soql query.